# How to connect object's timeline keyframe animation to an geometry proximity

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, add-on, keyframes, timeline

Can i connect object's animation(keyframes) to an another object(ico spheres), to play animation by distance, if ico spheres come close, it play towards, if ico spheres go backs, it plays backwards.
I need to do it with geometry nodes.

Need to mix this two tutorials:

https://youtu.be/H6CjBimRXUQ

https://youtu.be/7XRp68IVFHE?si=_C8DEKey3iMkum5k

I have geometry node based Flower bloom animation. And flower animated by keyframes on nodes values.
I connect this flowers to an other geometry nodes animation - when ico spheres comes closly, flowers are shows up, and if theres no ico spheres - flowers will not shows up.
So there is two geometry node groups.

And i need one more thing. I need to connect flowers blooming to these ico spheres, so they will responsible not only for show up animation, but also for blooming keyframes.

**Main problem - when ico spheres are not so close, flowers are not showing, but still blooming by their own geometry nodes(keyframe)
I cannot change keyframes on timeline maually, cause there is a lot of flowers.**